# Java recursive root function

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a function to find a root in java for a given function, it finds the root just fine, but when I go to return the root, it returns the initial value of m that I passed into the function and not the final one. I added a bunch of print statements in my function to make sure the value was being reached, and it is, my question is how do I pass the newest and not the oldest version of m out of my function? My code looks like this.

```
public static double bisect (double a, double b, double tolerance)      
{
    double m = (a+b)/2;
    double q = 0;
    while(q < tolerance){
        if (m*m*m - 2.0*m  - 3.0 == 0.0){
            return m;
        }
        else if((a*a*a - 2.0*a  - 3.0)*(m*m*m - 2.0*m  - 3.0)<0){
            q++;
            System.out.printf("%1.15f %1.15f %1.15f\n",a,m,b);
            b = m;
            bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);
        }
        else if((b*b*b - 2.0*b  - 3.0)*(m*m*m - 2.0*m  - 3.0)<0){
            q++;
            System.out.printf("%1.15f %1.15f %1.15f\n",a,m,b);
            a = m;
            bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);

        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

My print out looks like this

1.000000000000000 1.500000000000000 2.000000000000000

1.500000000000000 1.750000000000000 2.000000000000000

1.893289196304497 1.893289196304498 1.893289196304499

I cut out the hundreds of steps in between, but the 1.89 is the value I wanted to reach, just how do I get it out? Right now it returns 1.5 which is my initial value for m.

Comment: m is never assigned. Somehwere in that you have to do `m = something`. I'd be more specific but I (with great shame) have to review the math to suggest what value m should be assigned to.

Comment: I think you're structured the recursion wrong.  Currently all possible outcomes will return the initial value of `m`, because you never assign it a new value or return anything else.  My guess is those `bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);` lines should actually be `return bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bisect` returns a double. When you call it within the method (recursively), you don't do anything with the return value:

```
a = m;
bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);
```

You want to set the value of m to what you return:

```
a = m;
m = bisect(a,b,1.0e-10);
```

You can simplify this a bit further:

```
m = bisect(m, b, 1e-10);
```

I ended up simplifying this a bit when I was figuring out what it did, here's my simplified version. It might be useful?

```
public static double bisect(double a, double b, double tolerance) {
    double m = (a + b) / 2;
    double q = 0;
    while (q < tolerance) {
        if (m*m*m - 2*m - 3 == 0)
            return m;
        else if ((a*a*a - 2*a - 3) * (m*m*m - 2*m - 3) < 0)
            m = bisect(a, m, 1.0e-10);
        else if ((b*b*b - 2*b - 3) * (m*m*m - 2*m - 3) < 0)
            m = bisect(m, b, 1e-10);
        q++;
    }
    return m;
}
```